# How to unlock green lockers in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

I completed 16% of Silent Hill: Downpour, and I came across a green locker at the entrance of the town just after completing Devil's Pit episode. When I try to use it, it asks for a 6-digit password. What am I supposed to do? Is there something around to interact with in order to reveal possible passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't have the password is that you actually can't obtain them in the game - this locker is actually a sneaky way of unlocking bonus content.  These codes were available with preorders, but obviously they're universal.  You might try any of the following (I've left the actual weapons you get as a surprise for the curious): 353479,
171678, 911977.

You are likely to run into a few more of these as well; they'll all use the same set of codes, I believe.  (I am unsure if you can use a code twice but I expect the answer is 'yes'.)

Comment: That's really helpful. I'll try the codes as soon as I resume. Thanks!

Comment: I have used the code 171678 and unlocked the green locker. There was a _Nail Gun_ and a _Double Axe_ in it. However, once the locker is opened, the code cannot be entered anymore. Only one code can be entered per locker. So, one needs to find another locker to be able to enter another code.

Comment: @MehperC.Palavuzlar - Sorry, I thought that was obvious.  Once a locker is opened, it's opened.

Answer (score 1):

You can type in the code 911977, then you get a repeater and a 9 iron.