# Where are all the green lockers in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

A green locker is actually a sneaky way of unlocking bonus content. I could only [find one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/56180/how-to-unlock-green-lockers-in-silent-hill-downpour) at 16% of the game, and it was at the entrance of the town just after completing Devil's Pit episode. Now I finished the game and I didn't come across any of the rest.

Where are the green locker locations in Silent Hill: Downpour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this link :

http://www.rarityguide.com/articles/articles/1863/1/Silent-Hill-Downpour-Walkthrough-Part-11-Green-Locker-Codes/Page1.html

I'm quite sure that's all of them lockers.